# What is right solution for this probability problem?

Tags: probability

This drug can cure $90$% of all diseases. What is probabilty of successful healing at least $18$ people of $20$ people, who have taken the drug?

What is the right solution and why?

From my point of view: If drug can cure $90$% of diseases (I assume that each person has only one disease), then It will heal precisely $18$ people of $20$. Because $90$% of $20$ is $18$. So the answer would be $100$%. Other people I asked got different results.

Comment: What have you done so far? How to understand your second question?

Comment: @Karl I edited the question.

Comment: The $0.9$ is the **probability** a randomly selected person will be cured. The number of people cured out of $20$ has Binomial Distribution. We have a coin that has probability $0.9$ of landing head. What is the probability that in $20$ tosses we will get $18$ or more heads?

Comment: Your second question is still unclear, looks like a multiple choice question, where you don't show the answers to us, let us guess, but is it not you who wants help? Please look at your textbook/lecture notes and read the question more carefully. And think, what is the probability that the drug cures one out of one, one  out two,and so on. Then see what distribution is the right one and don't forget, it says *at least* in the text.

Comment: @Karl I think that It can be unclear too. This one question was in my exam with these exact sentences. That's why I posted question here.

Answer (score 1):

Let the random variable $X$ be the number of people healed. $X$ has a binomial distribution.

$$\begin{align}P(X\geq18)&=P(X=18)+P(X=19)+P(X=20)\\&=\binom{20}{18}(0.9)^{18}(0.1)^2+\binom{20}{18}(0.9)^{19}(0.1)+(0.9)^{20}\\&\approx0.6769\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Before answering this question, I flipped a coin twice.  I got two tails.  The probability of getting tails when flipping a coin is $\frac{1}{2}$, but this doesn't mean that I have to get exactly one tails when I flip a coin twice.

---

To compute the probability that $n$ out of the twenty people are cured, suppose we assign each person a number $1, 2, \cdots, 19, 20$.  Let's suppose the first $n$ people are cured, and the last $n$ people are not.  If we assume that any one being cured is independent of whether the other people were cured, the probability of this happening is
$$\underbrace{(0.9\times0.9\times\cdots\times0.9)}_{n\text{ times}} \times \underbrace{((1-0.9)\times(1-0.9)\times\cdots\times(1-0.9)}_{20-n \text{ times}}$$
which we can simplify to
$$(0.9)^n(1-0.9)^{20-n}$$
However, this only computes the probability that *one particular group* of $n$ people is cured (and the other $20-n$ people are not cured), and we want to know the probability that *any group* of $n$ people is cured.  Thus, we multiply this number by the number of possible $n$ person groups to get
$$\operatorname{Pr}(\text{Exactly }n \text{ people cured}) = {20\choose n}(0.9)^n (1-0.9)^{20-n}$$
Now, 
$$\operatorname{Pr}(\text{At least } 18\text{ people cured}) =  \operatorname{Pr}(\text{Exactly }18 \text{ people cured}) + \operatorname{Pr}(\text{Exactly }19 \text{ people cured}) + \operatorname{Pr}(\text{Exactly }20 \text{ people cured})$$
which rae306 has computed in his answer.

---

The value you computed, $20 \times 0.9 = 18$, is called the *expected value*, or average.  This means that if we used this miracle drug on many groups of $20$ people, on average $18$ would be cured in each group.  However, the would probably also be groups were not a single person was cured, groups where every person was cured, and everything in between.